# Nodejs development on Docker under Windows 10

Tags: node.js, docker, windows-10

I am trying to wrap my head around Docker and how to use it for development purposes.  I am developing on a Windows 10 environment.  I have the basic question, when doing development on Nodejs, lets say you modify a .js file.  Do you modify it on the host machine (Windows machine) and then push it to the docker container, or do you modify the file on the Docker container itself?  If I modify the file on the Docker container how do I do this?

Comment: Edit:  You seem to need a Windows 10-specific answer.  Docker is more of a Linux-oriented technology.  `docker run` has a command line switch `-v /path/to/host/file:/path/in/container` that allows you to link directories on the host to appear in the container at those paths.  However, the technological magic which allows seems to occur in Linux and not windows.  Thus, when running Docker in windows you generally need to set up a Linux VM that runs the actual docker server and containers. And, barring newer deveopments,  that's where files would seem to be required when using `-v`.

Comment: @Paul -- I'm not sure at all what that has to do with his question, which is more Node.js-Docker specific and not Windows. It's fine for the OP to mention that in case it is relevant, but it's really a tangential issue not a primary one.

Comment: If you have this very strange setup for development only (rather than develop on host, test in docker), then you can modify it anywhere and push it anywhere you like -- it is completely up to you how you shuffle stuff around without having a particular goal in mind. There are these setups where people really have a container running as their sole development platform, but as you do not know how to push within the container, then this is probably not your setup. In all other cases, change on host, deploy in container, test, repeat, push on host.

Answer (score 0):

You modify your source code from the comfort of you host environment (windows 10 or whatever you like) then you `COPY` that source to your container with a Dockerfile. Particularly, with nodejs you can use as follow:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

# replace this with your application's default port
EXPOSE 8888

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This image assumes that your application has a file named package.json listing its dependencies and defining its [start script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values).

```
+ my-nodejs-app
|  -Dockerfile
|  -package.json 
|  -server.js
|   ...
```

Finally, you can build and run the Docker image:

```
$ cd my-nodejs-app
$ docker build -t my-nodejs-app .

$ docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app -p 8888:8888 my-nodejs-app
```

---

Alternatively, you can mount your source directory as a volume and reduce all to one single comand (useful during development stage):

```
$ cd my-nodejs-app
$ docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script \
  -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app \
  -p 8888:8888 node:6 npm install && node server.js
```

Comment: My concern around this is, every time I do a change to the source code which will happen quite often during development I have to run through the whole process again.  This seems cumbersome, isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Maybe restarting a temporal container mounting your source code directory is even easier. Look the details in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

mounting a volume with the code your working is your best bet, so you don't run the process over and over.